# How to count lines including the ending new lines in Python?

Tags: python, io

I've been searching for a method to count lines that also includes the ending new line(s). A method like this does not work:

```
def file_len(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1
```

An example of a file could be `file.txt`:

```
line 1 (newline)
line 2 (newline)
line 3 (newline)
```

Since I couldn't get the code formatting to work (newline) here stands for an empty line (so there is a newline character at the end of the previous line). I would like the line count to be 4 but instead the function gives a value of 3. What should I do to accomplish this type of behaviour?

Comment: I have no idea; your given example returns `4`, just as expected.

Comment: I suggested an edit to your question to make it (in my opinion clearer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do in this case is count the lines (as you do with your code), but check whether the last line ends with a `"\n"` and if it does increment the counter by 1.

I also made a minor modification to get rid of the i + 1
and I added two prints for debugging.

```
def file_len(fname):
    # comment or remove next two lines after debugging
    import os ; print("file has a size of %d bytes" % os.path.getsize(fname))
    print("file contents: %r" %  open(fname).read())
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f, 1):
            pass
            # comment or remove next line after debugging
            print("line is %r" % l)
    if i > 0 and l.endswith("\n"):  # increase line count if last line ends with "\n"
        i += 1
    return i
```

My output looks like:

```
file has a size of 22 bytes
file contents: 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n\n'
line is 'line 1\n'
line is 'line 2\n'
line is 'line 3\n'
line is '\n'
```

I suggest you copy paste my exact code and show the output

Comment: file has a size of 24 bytes
file contents: 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n'
line is 'line 1\n'
line is 'line 2\n'
line is 'line 3\n'

Maybe I worded the question wrong. The last line is empty and the previous line has a new line character that should append the line count to 4, or at least does in text editors.

Comment: so in other words if the last line has a trailing `"\n"` you want it to count as an additional line. Will change my answer.